# After exporting to PDF (xelatex, pdflatex, pdfcslatex), a blank page is displayed

Tags: pdf, tex-core, blank-page, htxelatex

Output written on testmatrika.pdf (5 pages).I have a problem after compiling Czech tex to PDF, when instead of text on the page I see only a white blank page. I tried using pdflatex, pdfcslatex and the results were even worse than xelatex. I also had a problem with the display of Czech, but I managed to solve it.

I am using TEX LIVE 4.8.4+git20170127-2 OS Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa
Thank you for your help . bukman

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, czech]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} %jazyk dokumentu
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %kodování dokumentu
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % výstupní kódování
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setromanfont{DejaVu Serif}
\usepackage{fontspec} % řeší zahrnutí správných fontů pro LuaLaTeX a XeLaTeX
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
  

\begin{document}

\part{Přepis matrik rodných/křtěných\newpage{}}

\section{HLINSKO římskokatolická církev}

\subsection{ŘK Hlinsko sign.224 1837-1859; matrika rodná s indexem; litera M
pro vesnice}
\subsubsection{Matriky obce Hamry u Hlinska}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 7. nar. 8. pokřt. březen 1858 Hamry 35 u Hlinska Aloisie \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Petr kat. mlynář, syn Karla Petra výminkáře z Hamrů č.
35 a matky Anny rodem Kučerové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Josefa kat. dcera Jana Vaška výminkáře z Hamrů č. 27 a matky Doroty
rodem Kysové ze Studnic. Křestní list \sout{vydán 18 26/10 79}%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/1 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 10. nar. 11. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 15 u Hlinska Anežka \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Pešava, katolický půlník, syn Jana Pešavy výminkáře z
Hamrů č. 15 a matky Anny rodem Mudrochové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Františka kat. dcera Jana Duška půlníka z Habrovce č. 2 a matky
Anny rodem Divišové z Habrouče. Křestní list vydán 18 7/5 79%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/2 & \textbf{V databázi} & I33819 & \textbf{Poznámka} &  \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 15. nar. 16. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 60 u Hlinska Josefa \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- Jan Adámek kat. familiant, syn Josefa Adámka půlníka z Jeníkova
č. 6 a matky Doroty rodem Novákové z Vojtěchova - okresu Hlineckého;
\textbf{\uline{matka}} - Františka kat. dcera Josefa Vaška familianta
z Hamrů č. 60 a matky Teresie rodem Navrátilové z Hamrů. Křestní list
vydán 18 1/7 81 a 18 21/8 82%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/3 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 7. nar. 8. pokřt. březen 1858 Hamry 35 u Hlinska Aloisie \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Petr kat. mlynář, syn Karla Petra výminkáře z Hamrů č.
35 a matky Anny rodem Kučerové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Josefa kat. dcera Jana Vaška výminkáře z Hamrů č. 27 a matky Doroty
rodem Kysové ze Studnic. Křestní list \sout{vydán 18 26/10 79}%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/1 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 10. nar. 11. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 15 u Hlinska Anežka \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Pešava, katolický půlník, syn Jana Pešavy výminkáře z
Hamrů č. 15 a matky Anny rodem Mudrochové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Františka kat. dcera Jana Duška půlníka z Habrovce č. 2 a matky
Anny rodem Divišové z Habrouče. Křestní list vydán 18 7/5 79%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/2 & \textbf{V databázi} & I33819 & \textbf{Poznámka} &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 15. nar. 16. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 60 u Hlinska Josefa \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- Jan Adámek kat. familiant, syn Josefa Adámka půlníka z Jeníkova
č. 6 a matky Doroty rodem Novákové z Vojtěchova - okresu Hlineckého;
\textbf{\uline{matka}} - Františka kat. dcera Josefa Vaška familianta
z Hamrů č. 60 a matky Teresie rodem Navrátilové z Hamrů. Křestní list
vydán 18 1/7 81 a 18 21/8 82%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/3 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 7. nar. 8. pokřt. březen 1858 Hamry 35 u Hlinska Aloisie \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Petr kat. mlynář, syn Karla Petra výminkáře z Hamrů č.
35 a matky Anny rodem Kučerové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Josefa kat. dcera Jana Vaška výminkáře z Hamrů č. 27 a matky Doroty
rodem Kysové ze Studnic. Křestní list \sout{vydán 18 26/10 79}%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/1 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 10. nar. 11. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 15 u Hlinska Anežka \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Pešava, katolický půlník, syn Jana Pešavy výminkáře z
Hamrů č. 15 a matky Anny rodem Mudrochové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Františka kat. dcera Jana Duška půlníka z Habrovce č. 2 a matky
Anny rodem Divišové z Habrouče. Křestní list vydán 18 7/5 79%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/2 & \textbf{V databázi} & I33819 & \textbf{Poznámka} &  \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 15. nar. 16. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 60 u Hlinska Josefa \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- Jan Adámek kat. familiant, syn Josefa Adámka půlníka z Jeníkova
č. 6 a matky Doroty rodem Novákové z Vojtěchova - okresu Hlineckého;
\textbf{\uline{matka}} - Františka kat. dcera Josefa Vaška familianta
z Hamrů č. 60 a matky Teresie rodem Navrátilové z Hamrů. Křestní list
vydán 18 1/7 81 a 18 21/8 82%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/3 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 7. nar. 8. pokřt. březen 1858 Hamry 35 u Hlinska Aloisie \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Petr kat. mlynář, syn Karla Petra výminkáře z Hamrů č.
35 a matky Anny rodem Kučerové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Josefa kat. dcera Jana Vaška výminkáře z Hamrů č. 27 a matky Doroty
rodem Kysové ze Studnic. Křestní list \sout{vydán 18 26/10 79}%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/1 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 10. nar. 11. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 15 u Hlinska Anežka \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Pešava, katolický půlník, syn Jana Pešavy výminkáře z
Hamrů č. 15 a matky Anny rodem Mudrochové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Františka kat. dcera Jana Duška půlníka z Habrovce č. 2 a matky
Anny rodem Divišové z Habrouče. Křestní list vydán 18 7/5 79%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/2 & \textbf{V databázi} & I33819 & \textbf{Poznámka} &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 15. nar. 16. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 60 u Hlinska Josefa \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- Jan Adámek kat. familiant, syn Josefa Adámka půlníka z Jeníkova
č. 6 a matky Doroty rodem Novákové z Vojtěchova - okresu Hlineckého;
\textbf{\uline{matka}} - Františka kat. dcera Josefa Vaška familianta
z Hamrů č. 60 a matky Teresie rodem Navrátilové z Hamrů. Křestní list
vydán 18 1/7 81 a 18 21/8 82%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/3 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 7. nar. 8. pokřt. březen 1858 Hamry 35 u Hlinska Aloisie \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Petr kat. mlynář, syn Karla Petra výminkáře z Hamrů č.
35 a matky Anny rodem Kučerové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Josefa kat. dcera Jana Vaška výminkáře z Hamrů č. 27 a matky Doroty
rodem Kysové ze Studnic. Křestní list \sout{vydán 18 26/10 79}%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/1 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 10. nar. 11. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 15 u Hlinska Anežka \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Pešava, katolický půlník, syn Jana Pešavy výminkáře z
Hamrů č. 15 a matky Anny rodem Mudrochové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Františka kat. dcera Jana Duška půlníka z Habrovce č. 2 a matky
Anny rodem Divišové z Habrouče. Křestní list vydán 18 7/5 79%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/2 & \textbf{V databázi} & I33819 & \textbf{Poznámka} &  \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 15. nar. 16. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 60 u Hlinska Josefa \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- Jan Adámek kat. familiant, syn Josefa Adámka půlníka z Jeníkova
č. 6 a matky Doroty rodem Novákové z Vojtěchova - okresu Hlineckého;
\textbf{\uline{matka}} - Františka kat. dcera Josefa Vaška familianta
z Hamrů č. 60 a matky Teresie rodem Navrátilové z Hamrů. Křestní list
vydán 18 1/7 81 a 18 21/8 82%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/3 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 7. nar. 8. pokřt. březen 1858 Hamry 35 u Hlinska Aloisie \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Petr kat. mlynář, syn Karla Petra výminkáře z Hamrů č.
35 a matky Anny rodem Kučerové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Josefa kat. dcera Jana Vaška výminkáře z Hamrů č. 27 a matky Doroty
rodem Kysové ze Studnic. Křestní list \sout{vydán 18 26/10 79}%
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/1 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 10. nar. 11. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 15 u Hlinska Anežka \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- František Pešava, katolický půlník, syn Jana Pešavy výminkáře z
Hamrů č. 15 a matky Anny rodem Mudrochové z Hamrů; \textbf{\uline{matka}}
- Františka kat. dcera Jana Duška půlníka z Habrovce č. 2 a matky
Anny rodem Divišové z Habrouče. Křestní list vydán 18 7/5 79%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/2 & \textbf{V databázi} & I33819 & \textbf{Poznámka} &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\item 15. nar. 16. pokřt. duben 1858 Hamry 60 u Hlinska Josefa \textbf{\uline{otec}}
- Jan Adámek kat. familiant, syn Josefa Adámka půlníka z Jeníkova
č. 6 a matky Doroty rodem Novákové z Vojtěchova - okresu Hlineckého;
\textbf{\uline{matka}} - Františka kat. dcera Josefa Vaška familianta
z Hamrů č. 60 a matky Teresie rodem Navrátilové z Hamrů. Křestní list
vydán 18 1/7 81 a 18 21/8 82%
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\textbf{Matrika} & ŘKHlinsko224/131/3 & \textbf{V databázi} & & \textbf{Poznámka} & \
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run your code with XeLaTeX I get 5 pages of output, and all of them have text on it. Could you add the contents of your `.log` file to the question? That may give information on what is going wrong.

Comment: never use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %kodování dokumentu
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % výstupní kódování `with xetex

Comment: David - thank you; this are delete.

Comment: Marijn
the first three entries are OK. The following entries do not have a line below them that begins with the word Matrika 1. 7. nar. 8. pokřt. březen 1858 Hamry 35 u Hlinska Aloisie otec - František Petr kat. mlynář, syn Karla Petra výminkáře z Hamrů č. 35 a matky Anny rodem Kučerové z Hamrů; matka - Josefa kat. dcera Jana Vaška výminkáře z Hamrů č. 27 a matky Doroty rodem Kysové ze Studnic. Křestní list vydán 18 26/10 79
Matrika ŘKHlinsko224/131/1 V databázi Poznámka    There is a gap in the entry between Point 8. and 17. points 9-16 are missing, but they are listed in the script.

Comment: Marijm, Where should I upload the log FILE? It's too big to fit in here.

Comment: I guess you don't want your tables to float? Remove all lines that say `\begin{table}[h]` and `\end{table}`, but keep the lines that say `\begin{tabular}{cccccc}` and `\end{tabular}`.

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure if I understand your issue completely. You also get a pdf with 5 pages, but some are completely empty? Or partly empty? Or there is content missing but no actual empty space?

Comment: Marijn, here si for download final PDF (b efore delete {table} and log file https://1url.cz/WrVi2  . Marijn, yes you understand correctly - see download page

Comment: I added the \usepackage{xunicode} package and now the part from point 6 to the middle of Point 8 is not displayed. From Point 9, the rest of the document will be displayed correctly.

Comment: @bukman avoid `xunicode` also avoid `xltxtra` just use `fontspec`

Comment: If I run your example I get mutiple  warnings `LaTeX Warning: \`h' float specifier changed to \`ht'.` because of the mis-used `[h]` options and many of the tables are moved to the end, but there is no blank page? I would guess you do not want floats, replace `\begin{table}[h]` by `\begin{center}` and replace `\end{table}` by `\end{center}`

Comment: @David - this advice "avoid xunicode also avoid xltxtra just use fontspec" - is to degrade the resulting PDF. When I delete these two packages, I correctly stop displaying the document already from the middle of Point 2 to the middle of Point 8. The tables have been corrected and are displayed correctly.

Comment: @bukman no you did something wrong, xlxtra loads fontspec which you neeed but it is highly unlikely you need any of the other legacy code it loads, certainly the document here does not need either of those packages (of course you need `\setromanfont{DejaVu Serif}` after you load `fontspec` as it is defined by that package

Comment: @david - I removed the package xltxtra, unicode and a4wide (I replaced it with \usepackage{geometry}, but the problem with text loss in the resulting PDF persists. \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} %jazyk dokumentu
\usepackage{fontspec} %pro správné kodování Xelatex, LuaLATEX
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry} %nastavení okrajů stránky
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

Comment: please make a complete example in your question and add an image showing text loss. I see no missing text in the example here. Just tables floating to another page (which is the only purpose of the `table` enviroment)

Comment: @David - uThe above .tex script is fine. The problem is the resulting PDF, where the data that is in the .tex script is missing.

Here the resulting pdf, which shows the text and the rest of the white page, where the text that is written in the script is missing. 
PDF picture:
first page [link](https://ctrlv.cz/SKMY) next page [link](https://ctrlv.cz/RkvU)

Comment: I can not reproduce that. Your example unchanged produces 5 pages [which look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG1Mf.png) no blank pages

Comment: @David - here are the current tex, pdf and log files in the zip file [link](https://easyupload.io/rsxtsn) In PDF page 2 at the top text to properly fill the page to the bottom. On the left are the numbers 1, 2, 3, and then on the third side on the left is the number 11. Items numbered 4-10 in PDF are missing (in tex file they are).

Comment: @bukman ouch  If I use your tex from the zip with xlatex [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgQ9j.png) The pdf in your zip is completely corrupt it shows missing text and my pdf reader flags it as broken pdf with errors. It is going to be hard to debug how  your system generated that sorry. It is not your tex file at fault

Comment: @David-the problem is in Linux OS, TEX software (TEXLive)?